# how to change the placement of ag charts from top of the marker in the line series to the bottom?

Tags: reactjs, charts, ag-charts-react, ag-charts

Hey I have been trying to do this for quite some time now but I can not move the labels of the line series to the bottom of the line in ag grid charts. Does anyone know how to do this ? I have attached the example from the docs below.

So instead of having the labels (numbers) north of the marker I want them south.

```
const ChartExample = () => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    autoSize: true,
    data: getData(),
    theme: {
      overrides: {
        line: {
          series: {
            highlightStyle: {
              series: {
                strokeWidth: 3,
                dimOpacity: 0.2,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Road fuel prices',
      fontSize: 18,
      spacing: 25,
    },
    footnote: {
      text: 'Source: Department for Business, Energy & Industrial Strategy',
    },
    series: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        xKey: 'date',
        yKey: 'petrol',
        stroke: '#01c185',
        label: {
          enabled: true,
        },
        marker: {
          stroke: '#01c185',
          fill: '#01c185',
        },
        tooltip,
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        xKey: 'date',
        yKey: 'diesel',
        stroke: '#000000',
        marker: {
          stroke: '#000000',
          fill: '#000000',
        },
        tooltip,
      },
    ],
    axes: [
      {
        position: 'bottom',
        type: 'time',
        tick: {
          interval: time.month.every(2),
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Date',
        },
        label: {
          autoRotate: true,
        },
      },
      {
        position: 'left',
        type: 'number',
        title: {
          text: 'Price in pence',
        },
        label: {
          autoRotate: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  return <AgChartsReact options={options} />;
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS7w7.png)

I have been through the docs and can not find the solution. The api does not have an option for placement like the other series. Alternatively I was unable to use custom css but maybe someone has tried this before.

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

We have an option called 'tooltip'

[image]

```
tooltip: {
  position: {
    xOffset: 50,
    yOffset: 50
  }
},
```

Result:

[image: Result]

I've got a plunker ready for you: https://plnkr.co/edit/tPBhshaEcxVOLGJ7?preview

Further reading

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-charts/api/

Comment: Hi thanks for you response but I am specifically looking to move the label to the bottom of the marker. 

I already have tooltips implemented in the application. 

To be specific about my problem is that I have a chart with 2 lines and the labels are going on top of each other which kind of defeats the purpose of  them as it is not very visible so what I want is for one line series to have labels on top and the other below.

Comment: I got your point, you want to customize them for each line. Let me think...

Comment: Hey, can you check this out? One tooltip over the marker, one tooltip below the marker: https://plnkr.co/plunk/dq9jmztuGGl3KkO4

Comment: Like I said before I am good for tooltips haha. I need the labels adjusted which are visible on the chart without any interaction.

Comment: Can you share your code on plunker?

Answer (score -1):

The api does not have an option for placement like the other series. Alternatively I was unable to use custom css but maybe someone has tried this before.
I will suggest sample code..

Comment: Hey yeah I couldn't find a way out of the box doing it and I have read the docs from start to end haha. 

Please yes if you have code that has a work around I would greatly appreciate it !